# TargetFramework FrameworkDisplayName empty

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, target-framework

What is the effective difference between the following assembly attributes - that is, what runtime difference, if any, might occur.

```
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2", 
                            FrameworkDisplayName = "")]

[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2",
                           FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5.2")]
```

The 1st is produced by MSBuild (with warnings) when the build machine does not have the 4.5.2 reference assemblies (via targeting pack) installed. The 2nd is produced when the build machine has the reference assemblies installed (the warnings disappear). I feel that the 2nd is somehow more correct, but don't have any concrete facts to support this. Both binaries appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

***TargetFramework***

Identifies the version of the .NET Framework that a particular assembly was compiled against.

The TargetFrameworkAttribute attribute can specify a FrameworkDisplayName property to provide a more descriptive .NET Framework version string that is suitable for displaying to clients of the assembly

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

***FrameworkDisplayName***

Gets the display name of the .NET Framework version against which an assembly was built.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute.frameworkdisplayname(v=vs.110).aspx

The example below emphasis the correctness of the 2nd line you mentioned:

The following example applies the TargetFrameworkAttribute to an assembly and assigns both property values to indicate that the assembly was built using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

[assembly:TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2", 
          FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework, Version 4.5.2")]

namespace MyCompany.Utilities
{
   public class StringLibrary
   {
      // Members defined here.
   }
}
```

I hope that clears the question.

Comment: my question is, what difference does it make, if any?

Comment: The difference as I noted, is to indicate that the assembly was built using .NET Framework 4.5.2 both for Target Framework and Display name for readiness.

Comment: Let me emphasis:  TargetFramework indicate the assembly and much more important than  FrameworkDisplayName. 
FrameworkDisplayName indicate the name of assembly and not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this page in future, looking for a way to fix the empty "FrameworkDisplayName" (as I was), you can follow the steps below:

- Navigate to C:\Users\mudalig\AppData\Local\Temp
- Look for the file
  ".NETFramework,Version=[assembly's .net
  version].AssemblyAttributes.cs". eg.
  .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs
- Open the file and
  check the "FrameworkDisplayName" element. If it's empty, set it to the expected value. (eg. FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5.1")

> //  using System; using System.Reflection; [assembly:
>   global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1",
>   FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5.1")]

Some background on why this maybe important.
Sometimes you need to ensure that your binaries are reproducible, i.e. the hashes should match when you do a new build. If the source or target machine has an empty/incorrect value for this attribute, the metadata of the binary (dll, exe) will change and will not match the other one.

This was the case of us, and I had to spend two days trying to come up with a solution. Hopefully, this will be of use to someone.